# how to stop transmission in the midst of "verify local data"?

Tags: command-line, gui, file-sharing, bittorrent, transmission

I cannot seem to stop "verify local data":

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ transmission-remote -t all --stop
[2016-04-22 04:26:22.956 PDT] transmission-remote:  (http://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/) Couldn't connect to server
thufir@tleilax:~$
```

because I'm using the transmission GUI?

From the GUI, how do I stop a verification without purging data?

Answer (score 1):

`transmission-remote` interacts with `transmission-daemon`, which isn't started along with `transmission-gtk`, hence the error.

In any case, there's no direct way to stop a torrent from being verified (neither via the command line nor via the GUI).

However you can simply close Transmission via the GUI, and the torrent will be paused immediately skipping the verification. There's no risk of purging the data (if you change your mind you'll have to verify the torrent from the start again though).

Alternatively, from the command line, you could send a SIGTERM signal to to the process, which will be handled and intepreted in the same way of a closure from the GUI:

```bsh
pkill -x transmission-gt
```